# Unstability of DC chopper control through PI current controller

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, analog, switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter

We usually use a DC chopper to control a DC motor. For simulation purpose I have built the following circuit in which I have tried to control the armature current of a DC motor using a DC chopper, a PI current controller and a PWM modulator:

[image]

In my simulation circuit, I have modeled the electrical and mechanical parts of a DC motor. The mechanical part is modeled to generate the adequate back-EMF (The parameters of the DC motor are shown in the circuit). The current going through the motor is sensed through a Rsense=0.5 Ω and fed the PI controller through a voltage divider with a ratio of 0.5.
The output of the PI controller is fed to a non inverting amplifier with a gain of 1.71.

I used the gain amplifier because:

- **At steady state**:

Va=(Ra+Rsense)*Ia+Ea (Ia:Armature current and Ea:Back EMF).
Sabstituting Ea=Ke*W and W=(Kt*Ia)/B (W:Angular velocity, Ke:Back EMF coefficient and Kt=constant torque coefficient, and B:friction coefficient).

Va=(Ra+Rsense+Kt*Ke/B)*Ia. Substituting by the values given in the ciruict, we get:
Va=1.71*Ia.

The result is compared with a sawtooth signal of 5 kHz and 1 V amplitude (so the PWM modulator has a gain of 1).

The PI controller components are calculated using the following procedure described in a book:
[image]

When I simulate the circuit with different references at the reference input of PI controller, I get a stable output current for some values and unstable outputs for others.

When I set the reference input to 200 mV, 500 mV, 1.2 V and 1.75 V, the output is stable and the graphs look as follows:

[image]

[image]

For other values at the reference input, like 100 mV, 300 mV, 400 mV 700 mV, 1 V, the outputs are unstable and the PI controller hits upper input, and I do not understand why?

1. Could anyone please, help me to understand where do these instabilities come from? Why the output is stable at 200 mV and 500 mV references and unstable for 300 mV and 400 mV, even though these values are bounded between 200 mV and 500 mV?
2. Is it due to hysteresis of the comparator and switches (which is set to 100 mV).

NB:I attached the circuit for download, simulation and troubleshooting:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vyc_R12zWHrBsBJEP3vp1Ty6UkJSyS-Q/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I would recommend you try to extract from SIMPLIS the *control-to-output* transfer function, that is the starting point of any compensation strategy: if you apply a *stimulus* at the control input, how does that stimulus propagate to form *the response* that you will then regulate. Once you have that Bode plot in magnitude and phase, you can see where to place poles and zeroes to force crossover for a stable response. I would stay away from PI coefficients and exclusively deal with poles and zeroes (there is no subcircuit of the motor in your file).

Comment: @VerbalKint, Thanks for the recommendations and sorry for the attached file, I will update it now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tried to apply my automated macros to your circuit and it seems to correctly force crossover with a good phase margin. I slightly changed your circuit by replacing the op-amp with a subcircuit that I built. I can easily tweak the parameters and I know it converges well. I also changed the second non-inverting gain which was too high and had the error amp bias point too close to ground. In regulation, the error amp output is now biased close to 1 V which is ok:

[image]

The operating point indicates a 6-A current in the motor and all seems within expected boundaries:

[image]

The control-to-output transfer function exhibits an unusual shape but I can't judge without knowledge of this particular arrangement. The type 2 compensator is extracted from my free [ready-made templates](http://powersimtof.com/Downloads/Book/Christophe%20Basso%20SIMPLIS%20Collection.pdf) and it gave the following values:

[image]

The crossover frequency was arbitrarily set at 100 Hz and the phase margin is 60° at this point. As I said, I don't use PID or PI coefficients as they don't talk to me and most of the stabilization procedures are empirical. I always resort to poles and zeroes as I know where to place them and how they affect the overall shape. The final load step isn't bad-looking either. Good luck with this converter.

[image]

Comment: @ Verbal kint ..you are really good .

Comment: @Autistic, thanks but nothing really special and happy to help! : )

Comment: @VerbalKint, Thanks a lot for the Endeavour, your answer and ready-made templates helped me troublshoot my simulation model. Thanks again!!

Comment: @learndesign, with pleasure, glad if I could help you!